# Server responses fail corresponding to load test using JMeter

Tags: apache2, java

Using JMeter, I am load testing a web application that is hosted locally(Apache 2). When I am generating load like 5000+ virtual user, I saw more than 30% CPU is idle but still getting failed responses. Mostly it gives java.socketException. Will anybody please clear me If anything is going wrong from my end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you experience a problem described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page. If you absolutely sure that everything is fine with your server (CPU usage is far not only one metric which needs to be considered) you can work it around as follows:

1. Switch "Implementation" of all your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to `HTTPClient4`. The fastest and the easiest way of doing this is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults) configuration element
2. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
3. In *hc.parameters* file (same location: JMeter's /bin folder) add the following line:

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```

You need to restart JMeter in order to pick the new properties up

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will definitely try this.